# How do I connect 3 roles with different tables?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, mern

How should I make my models if the Adopters, Personnel, and Admin models should still be on the Users Model? Using MongoDB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru6FZ.png)